# How do i unit test promises using sinon, mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following implementation. How do i proceed with the unit test. I want to ensure that `processData` is only called once when success and `handleDecryptError` is called once when error.

My unit test throws me an error stating `AssertionError: expected 0 to equal 1` for `should.equal(getHandleDecryptErrorSpy.callCount, 1);`.

Implementation:

```
let getData = exports.getData = (err, res, param) => {

    ...

    return security.decryptJWE(jweParts[0], jweParts[1], jweParts[2], jweParts[3], jweParts[4], privatekey)
        .then(data => processData(data, param))
        .catch(error => handleDecryptError(error, param));
}

let handleDecryptError = exports.handleDecryptError = (error, param) => {
    log.error(message.ERROR_DECRYPTING.red, error);

    ..

    return;
}

let processData = exports.processData = (momData, param) => {

    log.info(message.SUCCESS.red);

    ...

}
```

Test case:

```
it('6. Response for data is empty string', (done) => {

        let getDecryptJWESpy = sinon.stub(security, "decryptJWE").rejects(message.ERROR_DECRYPTING);
        let getProcessDataSpy = sinon.spy(updateTask, "processData");
        let getHandleDecryptErrorSpy = sinon.spy(updateTask, "handleDecryptError");

        let response = {
            body: "",
            text: ""
        };

        updateTask.getData(null, response, ["TASKID"]);
        should.equal(getDecryptJWESpy.callCount, 1);
        should.equal(getProcessDataSpy.callCount, 0);
        should.equal(getHandleDecryptErrorSpy.callCount, 1);

        done();
    });
```

Comment: It will be much easier to test if your function returns the promise from `security.decryptJWE()`

Comment: @MarkMeyer so if i return my promise, how can i proceed to do my testing?

Comment: It's a little more than a comment can handle @shadow. See code below.

Answer (score 0):

It you return the promise from `updateTask.getData`, you can call it in the test and put the assertions in the `then()` attached to the call. Now the test can wait for `getData()` to resolve before trying any assertions:

```
it('6. Response for data is empty string', () => { // don't pass done

   return updateTask.getData() // return this promise and mocha will handle it
   .then(() => {
        // assertions will now run at the right time
        should.equal( /* etc */)
   }
```

Also, if you don't pass `done` in you can return the promise from the test and mocha will know when the test is finished.

Also, since you're using Sinon — Sinon has a nice [assertion library](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/assertions/) that you can use like: `sinon.assert.calledOnce(getDecryptJWESpy);`. This will give you nicer messages on failure that `equal`.

Comment: am i resolving my promise the correct way? `let getDecryptJWESpy = sinon.stub(security, "decryptJWE").resolves(message.ERROR_DECRYPTING)`

Comment: Is there anyway i can use `getProcessDataSpy` and  `getHandleDecryptErrorSpy ` to test for count inside the then()? Apparently it seems that they are still count 0 not matter what.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is wait for the promise. It's easier to use `async/await`:

```
it('6. Response for data is empty string', async () => {

    let getDecryptJWESpy = sinon.stub(security, "decryptJWE").resolves(message.ERROR_DECRYPTING);
    let getProcessDataSpy = sinon.spy(updateTask, "processData");
    let getHandleDecryptErrorSpy = sinon.spy(updateTask, "handleDecryptError");

    let response = {
        body: "",
        text: ""
    };

    try {
        await updateTask.getData(null, response, ["TASKID"]);
    } catch(ignore) {}

    should.equal(getDecryptJWESpy.callCount, 1);
    should.equal(getProcessDataSpy.callCount, 0);
    should.equal(getHandleDecryptErrorSpy.callCount, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first establish what you need to test and when your test case is completed. Also since your code uses callbacks instead of async await, it is easier to assert the result using done().

When success, Test that the processData is called only once with required args

When success test is complete when processData is called

Hence your test case becomes

```
it('6. Response for data is empty string', (done) => {
  let getDecryptJWESpy = sinon.stub(security, "decryptJWE").resolves(message.ERROR_DECRYPTING);
  let getHandleDecryptErrorSpy = sinon.stub(updateTask, "handleDecryptError");
  let getProcessDataSpy = sinon.stub(updateTask, "processData").callsFake(function fakeFn() {
    should.equal(getDecryptJWESpy.callCount, 1);
    should.equal(getProcessDataSpy.callCount, 1);
    should.equal(getHandleDecryptErrorSpy.callCount, 0);
    //The test is done only is this point is reached
    done();
  });

  let response = {
    body: "",
    text: ""
  };
  updateTask.getData(null, response, ["TASKID"]);
});
```

When failure, Test that the handleDecryptError is called only once with required args

When failure test is complete when handleDecryptError is called

Hence your test case becomes

```
it('6. Response for data is empty string', (done) => {
  let getDecryptJWESpy = sinon.stub(security, "decryptJWE").resolves(message.ERROR_DECRYPTING);
  let getProcessDataSpy = sinon.stub(updateTask, "processData");
  let getHandleDecryptErrorSpy = sinon.stub(updateTask, "handleDecryptError").callsFake(function fakeFn() {
    should.equal(getDecryptJWESpy.callCount, 1);
    should.equal(getProcessDataSpy.callCount, 0);
    should.equal(getHandleDecryptErrorSpy.callCount, 1);
    //The test is done only is this point is reached
    done();
  });

  let response = {
    body: "",
    text: ""
  };
  updateTask.getData(null, response, ["TASKID"]);
});
```

The code as is may not work, since I have not tested it, But according to me the structure of the test should be as above.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to be consistent either using callback or promise everywhere. Since `security.decryptJWE` using promise, we will make `getData` also uses promise.

```
let getData = exports.getData = (err, res, param) => {
  ...

  // add 'return' so `getData` returns promise
  return security.decryptJWE(jweParts[0], jweParts[1], jweParts[2], jweParts[3], jweParts[4], privatekey)
      .then(data => processData(data, param))
      .catch(error => handleDecryptError(error, param));
}
```

Seems like your test case want to test whether `handleDecryptError` is called or not, so you must use `rejects` instead of `resolves`. If use `resolves`, it will go to `processData` instead of `handleDecryptError`.

```
it('6. Response for data is empty string', () => {

  let getDecryptJWESpy = sinon.stub(security, "decryptJWE").rejects(message.ERROR_DECRYPTING); // update to use rejects
  let getProcessDataSpy = sinon.spy(updateTask, "processData");
  let getHandleDecryptErrorSpy = sinon.spy(updateTask, "handleDecryptError");

  let response = {
      body: "",
      text: ""
  };

  return updateTask.getData(null, response, ["TASKID"]) // add 'return' and 'then'
    .then(() => { // alternatively, we can use `async/await`
      should.equal(getDecryptJWESpy.callCount, 1);
      should.equal(getProcessDataSpy.callCount, 0);
      should.equal(getHandleDecryptErrorSpy.callCount, 1);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It is still throwing the same error that i have being receiving. `AssertError: expected handleDecryptError to be called once but was called 0 times`

Comment: @shadow interesting, have you changed `resolves` to `rejects`?

Comment: yup. I did, which is why I am still pondering what is wrong. Is there anything that i might have missed out?

Comment: @shadow maybe we need to do more inspection in the code. If it's possible to share the code in github, maybe I can help to take a look at it.